# Input field displaying as undefined in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the input value for a form field, but when I use the code below, the value displays as undefined.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
.controller('ContactFormCtrl',
   function (Contacts) {
     var contactForm = this;
     contactForm.contacts = Contacts;
     contactForm.contact = {};
     var mail=contactForm.contact.email;

     contactForm.onchange = function () {console.log(mail);};
 });


<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="contactForm.contact.email" class="form-control" ng-change="contactForm.onchange()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the controller as :

```
 .controller('ContactFormCtrl',
  function (Contacts) {
    var contactForm = this;
    contactForm.contacts = Contacts;
    contactForm.contact = {};
    contactForm.contact.email="";
    var mail=contactForm.contact.email;

    contactForm.onchange = function () {console.log(mail);};
 });
```

Currently, there is no email property with "contactForm.contact" object. So you need to initialize the email property and it will not give you undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `controllerAs` syntax then you should use alias there `contactForm`

```
<div ng-controller="ContactFormCtrl as contactForm">
 <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="contactForm.contact.email" class="form-control" ng-change="contactForm.onchange()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
 </div>
</div>
```

And the reason it is undefined is you have reinitialized controller `contact` object after `contactForm.contacts = Contacts;` which overrides the value of `email`.

**Update**

As discussed in chat you want to show email on blur as well as you want to call `onchange` function on email validate, for that you should have to use combination of directive `ng-change` with `ng-blur` then you should get rid off `ng-model-options` which don't suits your requirement.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="ContactFormCtrl as contactForm">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="contactForm.contact.email" class="form-control"
            ng-change="myForm.email.$valid && contactForm.onchange()" ng-blur="contactForm.onchange()"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I remove `contactForm.contact = {};` I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'email' of undefined`

Comment: @Ken you should not removed that, you should keep it..could I know `contacts` and `contact` are different?

Comment: I don't have a good reason for using `contact` and `contacts` in my example above. Any suggestions on how to fix my code to resolve the undefined issue?

Comment: @ken I don't understand how can `contactForm.contact.email` will contain any value after initialization of  `contactForm.contact = {}`

Comment: are you asking that after changing `contactForm.contact.email` value it should change in console.log?

Comment: When I enter an email, I want to see that email address in the console.log. I know that on page load, it will be empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75871/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-ken).

Comment: should I be making any changes to the code for the controller? I've copied your html, but am still getting undefined.

Comment: you don't need to make any changes in controller..you have made some mistake somewhere..do verify your form name..